# PHP ZipArchive still remains the path to the file even if the file is added without path

Tags: php, wordpress, php-ziparchive

guys! I saw a lot of posts talking about using ZipArchive and how to get rid of the path structure inside the zip.
So, here's my code:

```
$zipname = $post->post_title.".zip";
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);

foreach($gallery as $img) {
    $attachment = get_attached_file($img['id']);
    $zip->addFile($attachment, pathinfo($attachment,PATHINFO_BASENAME));
}
$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);
exit;
```

The problem is, that the zip file contains an image without path, f.e. /image.jpg and the same image in a multiple directories as it appears on the server /path/to/the/file/image.jpg.

So, I'm not sure why this is happening. Can somebody help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation of addFile](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php):

```
$zip->addFile($attachment, pathinfo($attachment,PATHINFO_BASENAME));
```

`pathinfo($attachment,PATHINFO_BASENAME)` is returning you the "base name", that is to say the file name (without the path). The second parameter is the name (with path) of the file **IN** the zip.

If you want to keep the complete path structure in your zip, you should remove this parameter:

```
$zip->addFile($attachment)
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, maybe I didn't get you right, but you see, I have it like this: $zip->addFile($attachment, pathinfo($attachment,PATHINFO_BASENAME)); where $attachment is the full path to the file. I use pathinfo to extract the filename only, thus the zip file would have the image like this : /images.jpg. But my problem is that the file is added as /image.jpg AND /path/to/file/image.jpg

Comment: Are you sure that, for some reasons, you are not opening a file that have been already created? As a good practice, you should check the output of the functions `open` and `addFile`(ie that they don't return `false`)